# Enable template if functor passed as argument takes no argument

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, variadic-templates, sfinae

I am trying to define two overload for a template function. 
First overload is generated if functor passed as an argument has no parameter otherwise second overload is generated. 
I started to implement like this :

```
template <typename R, typename... Types>
constexpr size_t argumentCount(R (*f)(Types...))
{
    return sizeof...(Types);
}

template <typename Function>
typename std::enable_if<argumentCount<Function>() == 0, int>::value = 0 > callFunc(Function fu)
{
    fu();
}

template <typename Function, typename... Params>
typename std::enable_if<argumentCount<Function>() == 0, int>::value = 0 > callFunc(Function fu, Params... params)
{
    fu(std::forward<decltype(params)>(params)...);
}
```

This does not compile for several reasons including parse error.What I want to do is,

`callFunc([](){});` will call overload 1 while `callFunc([](int value1,int value2){});` will call overload 2.

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: FWIW your last function will work with both cases.  Having `template <typename Function, typename... Params>
void callFunc(Function fu, Params... params)
{
    fu(std::forward<decltype(params)>(params)...);
}` lets you do `callFunc([](){});` and `callFunc([](int value1,int value2){}, 1, 2);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can add a level of indirection... what about using tag-dispatching instead of SFINAE?

I mean, something as follows

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename F>
void callFunc_helper (F fu, std::true_type)
 {
   std::cout << "zero version" << std::endl;

   fu();
 }

template <typename F, typename... Prs>
void callFunc_helper (F fu, std::false_type, Prs && ... params)
 {
   std::cout << "non zero version" << std::endl;

   fu(std::forward<Prs>(params)...);
 }

template <typename F, typename... Prs>
void callFunc (F fu, Prs && ... params)
 { callFunc_helper(fu, std::integral_constant<bool, 0u == sizeof...(Prs)>{},
                   std::forward<Prs>(params)...); }

int main ()
 {
   callFunc([]{});
   callFunc([](int, int){}, 0, 1);
 }
```

Obviously you can use `std::integral_constant<bool, 0u == argumentCount<Function>()>{}` if you really want to check the number of the functional arguments instead of the number of the following parameters (but why?).

Comment: Obviously this is very close to solution among the other ideas I tried. But this checks the number of parameters passed not the number of parameters that function accepts.

Comment: Consider , Qt Signal Slot implementation. where signal is passing arguments while slot does not have to take all parameters.

Comment: @MuhammetAliAsan - as explained at the end of the answer, if you want to select the correct function through the number of parameter accepted by the functional, you can use `std::integral_constant<bool, 0u == argumentCount<Function>()>{}` instead of `std::integral_constant<bool, 0u == sizeof...(Prs)>{}`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the detection idiom with `std::void_t` and `std::declval` to detect such features.

```
template <typename FuncT>
using invocable_without_args_t = std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<FuncT>()())>;
```

More information is [available here](https://blog.tartanllama.xyz/detection-idiom/); this post helped me a lot to understand how this works.

Answer (score 1):

1. Here is your version with a fixed syntax:

```
template <typename R, typename... Types>
constexpr size_t argumentCount(R (*f)(Types...))
{
    return sizeof...(Types);
}

template <typename Function>
typename std::enable_if<argumentCount<Function>() == 0, int> callFunc(Function fu)
{
    fu();
}

template <typename Function, typename... Params>
typename std::enable_if<argumentCount<Function>() == 0, int> callFunc(Function fu, Params... params)
{
    fu(std::forward<decltype(params)>(params)...);
}
```

2. In this particular example you do not need an extra overload, `Types...` can be empty.

```
    template <typename Function, typename... Params>
    auto callFunc(Function fu, Params... params)
    {
        fu(std::forward<decltype(params)>(params)...);
    }
```

works perfectly well.

Answer (score 0):

If you need two template functions, just write them:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class R>
void callFunc(R (*f)()) {
    std::cout << "Called no-arg template\n";
    f();
}

template <class R, class T, class... Types, class... Params>
void callFunc(R (*f)(T, Types...), Params... params) {
    std::cout << "Called multi-arg template\n";
    f(params...);
}

void g() {
    std::cout << "Called g\n";
}

void h(int) {
    std::cout << "Called h\n";
}

int main() {
    callFunc(g);
    callFunc(h, 3);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
[temp]$ clang++ -std=c++11 test.cpp
[temp]$ ./a.out
Called no-arg template
Called g
Called multi-arg template
Called h
[temp]$
```